# find the probability that the 2 integers product will be odd.

Tags: probability

Lets say I pick 2 integers between 3 to 7. Now i want to find the probability that the 2 integers product will be odd.

There are 25 choices and only 7 are odd but what is throwing me off is probability that 2 integers product will be odd. so do i do $\frac{7}{25} \times \frac{7}{25}$

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear whether  we are picking with replacement or not. Say with, and we pick one at a time. The probability the first is odd is $3/5$. Continue.

Comment: i believe we are picking the 2 integers at the same time

Comment: Hint:The product will be odd if both integers are odd.

Comment: @Justin: If we are picking without replacement, it is still useful for the analysis to imagine it is done one at a time. Then the probability the first is odd is $3/5$, and the probability the second is odd given the first is odd is $2/4$, giving probability $6/20$ instead of $9/25$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of two integers is odd if and only if the two integers are odd themselves. In this case, there are $3$ odd integers out of $3,4,5,6,7$.

Two possibilities arise because you question is not stated properly:

1)You can pick *with replacement*, that is you can pick $3$ twice, $6$ twice for the two numbers etcetera.Then the number of $($odd,odd$)$ pairs you can find is $9$. Hence your answer is $\frac{9}{25}$.

2)You can pick *without replacement*, that is you can't pick $3$ twice, $6$ twice for the two numbers , you have to pick two different numbers etcetera.Then the number of $($odd,odd$)$ pairs you can find is $6$, because you pick an odd number the first time, and the second time only two more odd numbers are left to ppick , giving $3*2=6$. Hence your answer is $\frac{6}{20}$ in this case, because now the number of cases is $20$, not $25$.

I don't see where $\frac{7}{25}$ comes from, because your explanation isn't quite clear, but this answer is correct anyway.